# JVM in Docker uses 100% CPU accross multiple cores

Tags: java, docker, jvm, cpu, cpu-usage

I have a Spring Boot app running in Docker which seems to struggle with its processing, I'll need to fix it.
Anyway, to get an idea of where the bottleneck is I made a simple `top`, I see that my Java process uses 100% CPU on a 4 cores machine. Good enough, I guess I need to parallelize some expensive actions in order to spread across multiple cores.

**The thing is even if my main Java process seems to max out around 100%, machine wise I see that all 4 cores are used around 25%.**
I'm clearly not an expert in Docker or JVM but I have to do something about it :/
To me, it looks like my JVM only see 1 core but docker manages to spread the work accross all cores.

Any thoughts about what might be going on ?
Oh and about the versions, it's running Docker 17.05, JDK 7. I might update Docker but not Java :(

Comment: What you said here is not yet a sign of a problem. What is the original problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Basically the app consumes AMQ messages and perform various Mongo operations with them.  
It used to run well, now it accumulates delay because the data input is bigger.  
I see that the java process is stuck around 98~102% CPU usage as if it was using a single core. But machine wise, all cores are around 25%.   
There is probably a reason why my Java process doesn't use say 150% CPU, maybe related to Docker.
+ I find it odd that the process seems to use only one core although its "workload" is spread over all 4.

Comment: OK, this information should have been in the question in the first place (please edit the post accordingly). The problem isn't necessary related to Docker at all. If the app communicates to Mongo, it likely waits for Mongo responses and thus cannot utilize 100% CPU in one thread. How many worker threads are there in your app? Did you try profiling?

Answer (score 0):

I faced such an issue on Docker on AWS EC2 with 64 cores. The problem was that only one core was visible when calling Java with no options. All cores were visible if I used `-XX:ActiveProcessorCount` or `-XX:-UseContainerSupport` options. But in the latter case each of the cores is used less than 2-3% summing all together to about 100%. After a long search I found that tools like htop can see all physical cores from the container but there could be constraints limiting the number of available CPU capacity. For instance, the option `--cpu-shares`. One can check its value from within the container with `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.shares`. The 1024 points correspond to 1 core. For example one can set `--cpu-shares 716` and only 70% of the core will be available from the container. This was my case. In your case the number of physical processors is 4 and probably cpu.shares has 1024 points. Thus, you load 25% of every core.

Useful links for reference:
[JVM in container calculates processors wrongly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661653/jvm-in-container-calculates-processors-wrongly)
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8146115
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/